# Show a set is open in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> I need to show that the following set is open in a given metric space
>
> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $x,y \in X$. Show that the set $A = \{z \in X: d(x,z) < d(y,z)\}$ is open in $(X,d)$.

I think I have to use the triangle inequality with a fixed point in $A$, but not sure how to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be given by

$$f(z) = d(x,z) - d(y,z).$$

We have that $A = f^{-1}\Big((-\infty, 0)\Big)$, so that it suffices to note that $f$ is continuous.
Explicitly, observe that

\begin{align}
|f(z_n) - f(z)|
&=
|d(x,z_n) - d(y,z_n) -d(x,z) + d(y,z)|
\\&=
\left|\Big(d(x,z_n) - d(x,z)\Big) + \Big(d(y,z) - d(y,z_n)\Big)\right|
\\&\leqslant
2d(z_n,z)
\end{align}

So we see that as $z_n\to z$ so too does $f(z_n) \to f(z)$, which completes the proof.
Notice that in the last step we used the triangle inequality as you suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch on how I'd go about proving this.

Pick a point $a$ in $A$ and let $\varepsilon = \frac{d(a,y) - d(a,x)}{2} > 0$. Then I claim that the open $\varepsilon$-ball centered at $a$ is contained in $A$. To show this, we need to show that for every $b$ in the open $\varepsilon$-ball, $d(x,b) < d(y,b)$.

Using the triangle inequality and the definition of the $\varepsilon$-ball, we can set up the following inequalities: $$d(x, b) \leq d(x,a) + d(a, b) < d(x,a) + \varepsilon$$
$$d(a, y) \leq d(y, b) + d(a,b) < d(y,b) + \varepsilon$$

Can you conclude from there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $d(y,z)=r_z+d(x,z).$

For $z\in A$ and any $w\in B_d(z,r_z/2)$ we have $w\in A$ because $$d(x,w)\le d(x,z)+d(z,w)<$$ $$<d(x,z)+r_z/2=$$ $$=d(y,z)-r_z/2 \le$$ $$\le d(y,w)+d(w,z)-r_z/2<$$ $$<d(y,w)+r_z/2-r_z/2=$$ $$=d(y,w).$$ So if $z\in A$ then $B_d(z,r_z/2)\subset A.$

And if $z\in A$ then $z\in B_d(z,r_z/2)$ because $r_z>0.$

Therefore $A=\cup_{z\in A}\{z\}\subset \cup_{z\in A}B_d(z,r_z/2)\subset A,$ so $A=\cup_{z\in A}B_d(z,r_z/2)$ is a union of open balls.

Remark: It may help to draw a picture to understand this. E.g. suppose $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric.

Remark: You might notice that the long sequence of inequalities is valid even if $z\not \in A.$ But if $z\not\in A$ then $r_z\le 0$ so "any $w\in B_d(z,r_z/2)$" is "any $w\in \emptyset$".